# Where is the leave message button in the lock screen?

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10, and I noticed there is no <kbd>Leave Message</kbd> button while my screen is locked.

Has it been removed, or is this just a bug?

Is there any way to bring it back?

Comment: I noticed this was removed too. Might have been a design change by upstream GNOME for the transition to GNOME 3, but I am not sure.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I would really like a feature like that... I'd like it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was intentionally removed in GNOME 3 because "it didn't really work
well." There does not appear to be any support for users who want to add it back.

Source: [Bug 656982 - Please return "Leave a message" feature to unlock choices](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656982)

Comment: looks like this was added again, how do I get rid of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/293120/disable-lock-screen-away-message