# How can I disable the lock screen away message in Cinnamon?

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen, cinnamon

I have an issue where the lock screen wants me to input an 'Away Message'. How can I disable this option?

This is with the Cinnamon window manager on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this is a cinnamon setting in

cinnamon -> System Settings -> preferences -> Screensaver & Lock Settings

uncheck the checkbox 'Ask for an away message when locking the screen from menu'